# What are the characteristics of a flip card in my library?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Are the characteristics of a flip card in my library determined by both faces or just the front face?

For example, can I use an [Enlightened Tutor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Enlightened%20Tutor) to fetch [Sasaya, Orochi Ascendant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sasaya%2C%20Orochi%20Ascendant)? Enlightened Tutor searches for enchantments and artifacts. If Sasaya is only an Enchantment after she's flipped, does that count?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your library, a flip card has only the characteristics of the top half of the card. You cannot use Enlightened Tutor to find Sasaya, Orochi Ascendant, because

> In every zone other than the battlefield, and also on the battlefield before the permanent flips, **a flip card has only the normal characteristics of the card.** (CR 709.2, emphasis added)

(From 709.1a and 1b, the top half defines the "normal characteristics", and the bottom half defines the "alternative characteristics".)

Basically, until it's actually flipped, the card/spell acts as if the flip version wasn't printed on it, so neither the tutor nor the enchantress will ever do anything with it (since it's not an enchantment either when you cast it).

Comment: This is nicely illustrated in the flip list card which you can use instead of the flip card due to the non generic background, only the front name is on that card.